# Generates signed apk file in project that used the org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar file

Tags: android, nfc, open-mobile-api, secure-element

I used **org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar** in my project.

When I use:

- "provided files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')" in my project's app gradle all things looks OK
- "compile files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')" in app gradle or I create sign apk file, my project not work properly.

The problem occurs when i want open logical channel, this time occurred security exception:

> (java.lang.SecurityException: Access Control Enforcer: no APDU access
>   allowed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occur on sign apk due to Pro guard . Add Pro guard rule for org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar. or make  minifyEnabled false on build.gradle file.